# Cypress HostName Plugin Not Responding

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cypress

I created a plugin in plugins/index.js

```
const os = require('os');


module.exports = (on, config) => {
  config.env.testing_computer = os.hostname();
  return config;
}
```

Basically I want to store the hostname in the environment variable testing_computer.
However when I try to access it later in a custom command by Cypress.env("testing_computer") it is an empty string. How can I get the actual value?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I cleared the rest of the file and left only the new plugin. I think the line at the top <references... may have been causing trouble, though I'm not sure.